# I'm trying to clip an image overlay in Google Maps API

Tags: image, api, maps, overlay, crop

I'm trying to clip an image overlay in Google Maps API, however without success. I can clip a HTML image successfully and overlay it on a Google MAP by using the CSS `clip` property and `z-index` property, however that's no use, as the image does not adjust to the Google map zoom and movements. i.e. the image is not bound to the Google MAP object in any way, doesn't respond to map changes.

If I assign the Google Map overlay to the cropped  image source, it simply uses the original un-cropped source and not the cropped page image element. That's just how the `image.src` property works.

I successfully added an image overlay for Google MAPS, but there does not seem to be any clipping or cropping function for them. There is text on the image that I don't want to display for this application, but I don't want to crop the original source file image, as it's used for multiple display purposes.

```
historicalOverlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(imageurl,imageBounds);
historicalOverlay.setMap(map);
```

I need `imageurl` to point to a clipped version in memory or something like that or the clipped form image element, but not its un-clipped source image. Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you come right with this? I would like to know as I would like to clip a png image based off geojson polygon data and overlay just the image inside polygon. Thinking of redrawing with image by converting lat/lng to pixels and blacking out the pixels outside the polygon, then setting black to alpha channel so the image you load is redrawn. I understand that mapbox / leaflet do this perfectly, but I am limited to google maps

Answer (score 0):

The GroundOverlay class in Google Maps javascript API V3 does not provide any support for in-browser clipping/cropping of the image before display.

Because we needed that capability, plus some others like image rotation and non-rectangular images, we wrote a GroundOverlayEX javascript class that supports everything that the Google Earth version of GroundOverlay supports, including browser-side clipping/cropping of the image to-be-displayed.

The javascript class is open-source on Github at: https://github.com/azmikemm/GroundOverlayEX.  There is API documentation as well (documentation.txt). All images shown by the GroundOverlayEX class are integral to the map, and will drag with the map, and zoom with the map.

A working functional example of the class in-action (with some clipped/ cropped images) is at: https://sites.google.com/site/issearthatnight/
If you turn off the VIIRS checkbox, and set the transparency down to midway, you'll see the images pretty plainly, and see that some are cropped (all are stored in NASA's servers as rectangles, so images that are square-ish or look like slices have been cropped by the GroundOverlayEX class).

Comment: Is it possible to clip/crop based on polygon information? Only show the picture based on specific bounds? I read the js above and see you can crop up/down/left/right, but would like to fit the image to the polygon overlay - been battling with that for weeks now and trying to figure it out